# My opponent won despite his king having no legal moves

Tags: checkmate

My opponent won despite his king having no legal moves. Why?

[image]

Comment: looks like you lost on time? note that he still has a pawn and can technically checkmate you

Comment: Whether the enemy king hast any legal moves does not matter.

Comment: That happens a lot. At the start of every game, neither player's king has any legal moves. Nevertheless, one of the players often goes on to win.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this beginners question keeps being posted again and again (mods, please insert link here):

"Stalemate" is NOT "king has no legal move".

"Stalemate" is "stalemated king is not in check" AND "no piece of the stalemated side has a legal move".

In your case, it is true that your king is not in check and has no legal move, but your pawn on h6 (h7?) still can move.